# Level of difficulty in the title with package xsim

Tags: xsim

I would like to indicate the level of difficulty in the title of the exercise with the package xsim.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside,french]{article}

\usepackage{xsim}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\DeclareExerciseTagging{difficulty}

\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{custom}{%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        width=\textwidth,
        enhanced,
        breakable,
        colbacktitle=\IfInsideSolutionTF{olive}{red},
        colframe=\IfInsideSolutionTF{olive}{red},
        coltitle=black,
        colback=white,
        sharp corners,
        beforeafter skip=\baselineskip,
        title={\bfseries\XSIMmixedcase{\GetExerciseName}~\GetExerciseProperty{counter}\qquad\IfExerciseTagSetTF{difficulty=1}{\normalfont(Niveau 1)}{}}     
        ]
        }
    {\end{tcolorbox}}

\xsimsetup{
    exercise/template=custom,
    solution/template=custom,
    solution/print=true
}

\xsimsetup{solution/print=true}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}[difficulty=1]
    Exercice niveau 1 
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
    Solution de l'exercice 1
\end{solution}

\begin{exercise}[difficulty=2]
    Exercice niveau 2
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
    Solution de l'exercice 2
\end{solution}

\begin{exercise}[difficulty=3]
    Exercice niveau 2
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
    Solution de l'exercice 1
\end{solution}



\end{document}
```

So I tried with the line `\qquad\IfExerciseTagSetTF{difficulty=1}{\normalfont(Niveau 1)}{}` (and of course I would add the same for difficulty=2, and 3) but nothing appears.
The text "Niveau 1" is just for the MWE. In the final version, I think I will use 1 emoji thinking face for difficulty=1, ...
I guess my test `\IfExerciseTagSetTF{difficulty=1}` is not correct.